# How do point sprites work when using different versions of GLSL/OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-3

As I understand it, `gl_PointCoord` is always available in the fragment shader in OpenGL 3 when rendering points; but, on the other hand, the GLSL 1.20 specification says that it is only available when "point sprites are enabled" (which I assume means after a call to `glEnable(GL_POINT_SPRITE)`).

Seeing as how those two statements conflict, and `GL_POINT_SPRITE` is not available in OpenGL 3, when is `gl_PointCoord` actually available? Does it depend on the `#version` directive, or on the GL profile one has obtained, or what?

Further, how does this interact with the point shape? As far as I understand it, points are rendered as squares when MSAA is turned off, and as circles when MSAA is turned on. When `GL_POINT_SPRITE` is available, they seem always to be rendered as squares when it is enabled, quite simply, but how would one control this properly in OpenGL 3? Is one supposed to simply turn multisampling off around point rendering calls when one wants them square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gl_PointCoord` is *always* "available" (filled with meaningful values) for `GL_POINT` primitives in **core** OpenGL. In compatibility profiles or an implementation that does not provide GLSL 130, you will have to enable `GL_POINT_SPRITE`.

Comment: "This is what you are actually referring to when you discuss points either being square or round." -- No, when I turn MSAA on, points are rendered as circles. I never touch the `GL_POINT_SMOOTH` state.

Comment: Ah, yes that was changed. You can change this behavior by enabling or disabling MSAA in newer versions of OpenGL. It mirrors the behavior of `GL_POINT_SMOOTH` in old-school OpenGL.

Comment: So that I properly understand the first part of your answer, are you saying that as soon as I get a compatibility profile (even OpenGL 4 Compatibility, and use the latest GLSL `#version`), I need to enable `GL_POINT_SPRITE` to be sure that `gl_PointCoord` is available? Is it also safe to assume that it's always available in GLES2+?

Comment: You should not need to enable it if you use a `#version` greater than or equal to 130 for all of your shader stages. As for GLES 2.0+, yes, this is always available no hoops to jump through.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a relevant bug here: The Windows 7-10 drivers for the Sandy Bridge GPUs always return (0,0) for `gl_PointCoord` in a GL 3.1 core profile, regardless of whether you use `glEnable(0x8861)`. The drivers work correctly in a compatibility profile.